# How to mask a string that contains phone number in Oracle?

Tags: string, oracle, masking

I have a table like below;

```
ID(int) | P_DATE(date) | EXPLANATION(varchar2)
-----------------------------------------------
1       |   22.12.2013 |   'File upload'
2       |   31.12.2013 |   'Card Payment'
3       |   24.02.2014 |   'Unit TN=5321234564'
```

In third row of `Explanation` column, there is a phone number (5321234564)

How can I mask this phone number using '*'?

After masking, select query should be return the result like below?

```
ID(int) | P_DATE(date) | EXPLANATION(varchar2)
-----------------------------------------------
1       |   22.12.2013 |   'File upload'
2       |   31.12.2013 |   'Card Payment'
3       |   24.02.2014 |   'Unit TN=532*****64'
```

Comment: [`regexp_replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/olap.112/e17122/dml_functions_2068.htm) will serve your need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change query then it is simple:

```
select 'Unit TN=5321234564', regexp_replace('Unit TN=5321234564', 'TN=([0-9]{3})([0-9]{5})([0-9]{2})', 'TN=\1*****\3') from dual
```

(of course change regexp if your phone number is in other format)

If you cannot change query then rename original `EXPLANATION` column to `EXPLANATION_ORIG`, add `EXPLANATION` column and add trigger changing INSERT'ed or UPDATE'd data to save original data into `EXPLANATION_ORIG` and masked data into `EXPLANATION` column.

Comment: One more thing, there are datas that are not phone number but have numeric value. Example : `'Record TN=24668210458 FN'`. I dont want to mask these datas. How can I? @MichalNiklas

Comment: Then regexp can use "Unit" and `$` which means "end of string": `regexp_replace('Unit TN=5321234564', 'Unit TN=([0-9]{3})([0-9]{5})([0-9]{2})$', 'Unit TN=\1*****\3')`

Comment: If your masking code is too big then create database stored function that masks phone numbers.

Comment: select query is stored in stored procedures also. Thanks for all your help @MichalNiklas